# Given a 3D image array, return a list of indices with a value above a threshold and a minimum distance between all selected indices?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D numpy array that represents a 3D image and I want to create a list from it with all the (x,y,z) coordinates/index tuples that are both above a certain value, and within a certain distance from other coordinates also above that certain value. So if coords (3,4,5) and (3,3,3) were both above the value, but the minimum distance apart was 4, then only one of these coords would be added to the new array (doesnt matter which).

I thought about doing something like this:

```
arr = [(x,y,z) for x in range(x_dim) for y in range(y_dim) for z in range(z_dim) if original_arr[z][y][x]>threshold
```

To get arr, which contains all coordinates above the threshold. Im stuck on how to remove all coordinates from array 'arr' which are then too close to other coordinates also inside it. Checking each coordinate against every other coordinate isnt possible, as due to the image being very large it would take too long.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your threshold checking with:

import numpy as np

```
arr = np.argwhere(original_array> threshold)
```

The rest depends on your `arr` size and data type(please provide image size and dtype to assist better). If the number of points above the threshold is not too high you can use:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
euclidean_distances(arr,arr)
```

And check for distance threshold. If it is a high number of points, you can check via a loop iteration(I usually try to avoid changing loop variable array inside the loop, but this will save you a lot of memory space and time in case of large image):

```
arr = np.argwhere(original_array>threshold)
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
  try:
    diff = np.argwhere(np.sum(arr[i+1:,:]-arr[i,:], axis=1)<=distance)
    arr = np.delete(arr, diff+i+1, axis=0)
  except IndexError as e:
    break
```

your `arr` will contain coordinates you want:

output for sample code:

```
original_array = np.arange(40).reshape(10,2,2).astype(np.int32)
threshold = 5
distance = 3
```

arr:

```
[[1 1 0]
 [4 1 1]
 [8 1 1]]
```

distance matrix between final points:

```
[[0.         3.16227766 7.07106781]
 [3.16227766 0.         4.        ]
 [7.07106781 4.         0.        ]]
```

***EDIT***: per comment, if you want to ignore distance along `z` axis, replace this line:

```
diff = np.argwhere(np.sum((arr[i+1:,:]-arr[i,:])[:,0:2], axis=1)<=distance)
```

Comment: How would this work if we didn't care how close coordinates are in the z axis?

Comment: @Jaxon Please find my edit on the question for your answer. Thank you.

Comment: It works well for the first index of z, where it equals zero, but not for the rest. I'm getting a result like [ [ 0 39 241 ], [0 56 206 ] ... [ 0 464 216], [ 11 481 240 ] ]. I'd like to get something that works across all z values, going up one at a time

Comment: @Jaxon I am not sure what you mean. when you say you don't care about z axis distance, do you mean you want the points to have a minimum distance in the x-y plane or something else? That was my understanding. Maybe you can elaborate on what you mean by _we didn't care how close coordinates are in the z axis_ and _I'd like to get something that works across all z values, going up one at a time_. Thank you

Comment: Yes, I'd like the points to have a minimum distance in the x-y plane

Comment: @Jaxon Then by your definition, the above code should work. What seems to be the issue with the output in that case?

Comment: For an array with 400000 coordinates after thresholding, I get the following output: [[  0  39 241]
 [  0  56 206]
 [  0  73 226]
 [  0  90 107]
 [  0 107  87]
 [  0 124 192]
 [  0 141 108]
 [  0 158  78]
 [  0 175 118]
 [  0 192  39]
 [  0 209 133]
 [  0 226 168]
 [  0 243  72]
 [  0 260  85]
 [  0 277   5]
 [  0 294  13]
 [  0 311 222]
 [  0 328  55]
 [  0 345  43]
 [  0 362  14]
 [  0 379 138]
 [  0 396  91]
 [  0 413 200]
 [  0 430 193]
 [  0 447 219]
 [  0 464 216]
 [  7 474 224]
 [ 20 478 190]
 [ 32 483 219]
 [ 52 480 198]
 [ 70 487 147]]

Comment: @Jaxon what is wrong with this output? Please keep in mind you have not provided any details on your threshold, your image file and your minimum desired distance, therefore, this output includes not much information as to what the problem could be. Maybe you can explain it a little bit or provide the image and thresholds and min distance.

Comment: The threshold is equal to the 97th percentile of the intensity values in the image, the image file is a TIFF format containing an MRI scan and the minimum distance is 16. I was hoping to have something that would find the coordinates of the volumes of highest intensity across the image without having them cross-over

Comment: I am still not sure what is wrong with the output. Maybe you want to sort the output according to z? if not, you might wanna formulate your question differently, so that it addresses your goal better.

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm writing coordinate in the form (z, y, x), not (x, y , z). I changed [:,0:2] to [:,1:3] and it gives me the correct output for when z = 0, but I'd like to get the coordinates across all z values. The image dimensions are 72 for z, 512 for y and 318 for x, but only 13 coordinates are returned. I'm expecting something like 13 * 72 coordinates. Sorry I'm struggling to explain

Comment: Your output has z-values greater than 0. What you changed is correct. What you are trying to achieve is different than your question. Even if you iterate the loop for each z, there is not guarantee that the number of selected points for different z are the same (in this example 13). You might want to reformulate your problem and post a different question with details.